# Live wallpapers in android

Tags: android

i'm doing Android Live Wallpaper programmitically.I tried an example from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/Android/AndroidLiveWallpaper.aspx .WHen i run..i got error message on console as

"No Launcher activity found!
The launch will only sync the application package on the device!".How could i recover from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's fine. Ignore the warning.

It's basically saying you can't start the 'activity' from the menu. But you don't have an activity you have a live wallpaper :-)

Just Long click the home screen > LiveWallapers > and you will see it installed here.

Comment: Oh..thanku for ur reply.it works fine.But one more issue..How could i make more wallpapers as a list so the user can select one to set.?

Comment: it should be like `Wallpapers > Live wallapers`